# R: Optimizing a For Loop when input data frame is very large

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I have a huge dataframe called `ppiensemble`, containing almost 5 million rows. Here is a sample:

```
> head(ppiensemble, 10)
          protein1        protein2
1  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000020673
2  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000054666
3  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000158762
4  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000203407
5  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000203630
6  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000215071
7  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000215115
8  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000215375
9  ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000215565
10 ENSP00000000233 ENSP00000215574
```

The goal here is to convert all items in the column `protein1` to an alternate ID coming from a separate dataframe called `idconversiontable`. I want to extract the corresponding character in `idconversiontable$From`. Note as well that `idconversiontable` has only around 50000 rows:

```
> head(idconversiontable, 10)
                To   From
1  ENSP00000167825 Q9HCE6
2  ENSP00000355060 Q9HCE6
3  ENSP00000364564 Q9HCE6
4  ENSP00000244303 Q9Y2N7
5  ENSP00000300862 Q9Y2N7
6  ENSP00000366898 Q9Y2N7
7  ENSP00000255324 Q9BXT8
8  ENSP00000255325 Q9BXT8
9  ENSP00000322242 Q8N5U6
10 ENSP00000415682 Q8N5U6
```

So, I try to do that below by setting up a vector called `demo1` for `protein1`. It works for small sets, but this is just ridiculous...it's taking forever. Plus, I will eventually do the same for `protein2` as well. Any ideas on how to expedite this process?

```
demo1 <- vector(mode="character", length=nrow(ppiensemble))
for(i in 1:nrow(ppiensemble)) {
  demo1[i] <- try(ifelse(ppiensemble$protein1[i] %in% idconversiontable$To,
  as.character(idconversiontable[which(idconversiontable$To == ppiensemble$protein1[i]), 2]),
  "NA"))
    }
```

Additionally (under the same topic of "optimization"), is there a way to print a message every time 5000 rows are done (i.e., everytime i == a multiple of 5000)?

Comment: You're right, this approach _is_ ridiculous. This operation is called a join. Base R's `merge` will work much faster than this, but doing it with either **data.table** or **dplyr** will probably be very fast. I'd put good money on 1-2 seconds or less.

Comment: @joran thanks for feedback. Could you give an example of how **data.table** might be useful in this case?

Comment: Not any better than **data.table**'s documentation could. But Martin's answer is also very good, and very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of your conversion table as a map

```
map = setNames(idconversiontable$From, idconversiontable$To)
```

Then use the names on the map to go from protein id to gene symbol

```
genes = map[ppiensemble$protein1]
```

This 'just works' when looking up symbols that aren't present, e.g.,

```
map = setNames(c("a", "b"), c("A", "B"))
map[c("A", "C")]
##   A <NA> 
## "a"   NA
```

or maybe a slightly improved (?) version

```
unname(map[c("A", "C")])
## [1] "a" NA
```

Comment: it seems that all `ppiensemble` ids return an `idconversiontable$From` symbol. Is there any way to return an `NA` when the protein id is not found in the map?

Comment: @HenriW this 'just works'; I've tried to update my answer to illustrate. If you mean 'returns the character string "NA"', then I wouldn't recommend that; you could post-process as mapped[is.na(mapped)] = "NA", but again, I wouldn't recommend that!

Comment: As I stated in the OP, the ids in protein1 can either encapsulate a whole cell in idconversiontable$To, or just a string within a cell. This means that there may be multiple ensembl ids in one cell in the idconversiontable, separated by text and corresponding to a single protein id. Any ideas of how I could correct for this blunder?

Comment: @HenriW I don't know what you mean by 'a whole cell' and 'just a string within a cell'; please edit your question to clarify with an explicit example.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. I updated the question with an example of some of the "string within a cell" conversion lines I was talking about. So, I want to return the `idconversiontable$From` value if the corresponding row of `idconversiontable$to` **contains** `protein1`, not if it is equal to `protein1`.

Comment: forget about the "string within a cell" issue; I expanded the data to the usable format.